# Why do I receive undefined method after dynamically building array of Objects? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm building a most viewed post feature for a simple blog. Each post has a view count that is increased when the Show action is called for that particular post. Then on the Dashboard , I'm trying to list the top 5 posts. So far my code works and returns an array of posts with the post with the highest number of view count being the first index and the last index in the array being the post with the lowest view count. The only thing is when I try to iterate through the array in the view , the view returns:

**ERROR**

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

WHY??? Does it have to do with the "#" infront of the object?

Heres my code.

**Dashboard View**

```
<h3> Post </h3>
<% @top_posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller Methods**

```
def get_top
 @top_posts = []
 counts = []
 @posts = Post.all

 @posts.each do |post|
    counts << post.view_count
 end

 @posts.each do |post|
    if counts.max(5).include?(post.view_count)
        counts.max(5).each do |n|
            if n == post.view_count
              @top_posts[counts.max(5).index(n)] = post
            end
        end 
    end
  end

end


def dashboard
  @posts = Post.all
  get_top
end
```

**The Top Podcast Array of objects**

```
[#<Post id: 6, title: "Post 6", desc: "", tags: "", view_count: 8, s_desc: "", c_photo: nil, photos: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 06:02:25", updated_at: "2017-06-15 01:38:40", featured: nil>, #<Post id: 3, title: "post 3", desc: "", tags: "", view_count: 5, s_desc: "", c_photo: nil, photos: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 05:35:32", updated_at: "2017-06-14 05:35:53", featured: nil>, #<Post id: 5, title: "Post 5", desc: "", tags: "", view_count: 4, s_desc: "", c_photo: nil, photos: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 06:02:20", updated_at: "2017-06-15 01:38:31", featured: nil>, nil, #<Post id: 4, title: "Post 4", desc: "", tags: "", view_count: 3, s_desc: "", c_photo: nil, photos: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 05:49:29", updated_at: "2017-06-15 01:38:50", featured: nil>]
```

Comment: The Hell for the Sinful Ruby Interpreters is full of code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer would probably solve your error, but just want to make an attempt to optimize your code.
That array, loop, etc. is unnecessary, ask your db to do that stuff and get the top posts. Fetching all posts and looping over it multiple times...nay, try the following, hopefully this is what you are looking for..

```
@top_posts = Post.order('view_count desc').limit(5)
```

That's it, your view needs no change and will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@top_posts << post
```

instead of:

```
@top_posts[counts.max(5).index(n)] = post
```

You don't need to set the array index.